# Bypass cookie validation

Tags: xss, cookies

I have discovered that a web application allows the setting of certain cookie values through request parameters. Each request param results in a separate Set-Cookie header. i.e. a request like this:

```
/url?cookie1=first_value&cookie2=second_value
```

results in the following headers:

```
Set-Cookie: cookie1=first_value
Set-Cookie: cookie2=second_value
```

These headers appear after the session id cookie header, so I figure I should be able to fix the session by using a cookie value like the following

```
first_value; another_cookie=another_value
```

URL encoding the space, semicolon and equals signs. However once the app sees the semicolon, it simply truncates up to that point, so the response header becomes:

```
Set-Cookie: first_value
```

My question is, what other delimiters might a browser accept, or what methods might allow the filter to be bypassed.

Answer (score 2):

A CRLF Injection might work. You would use a URL like the following:

```
/url?cookie1=first_value%0d%0aSet-Cookie:%20cookie2=second_value
```

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work. The app truncates the query value up to the CRLF.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is an old, mostly-obsolete value for the CGI record separator, but it's still recognized by many CGI scripts.  Most likely what's happening is that your

```
/url?cookie1=first_value;another_cookie=another_value&cookie2=second_value
```

is being interpreted as

```
cookie1=first_value
another_cookie=another_value
cookie2=second_value
```

and since the CGI script doesn't know what to do with a parameter named `another_cookie`, it ignores it.  You can probably get around this by percent-encoding your semicolon:

```
/url?cookie1=first_value%3Banother_cookie=another_value&cookie2=second_value
```